# In OpenShift, Deploy application from web console using image name

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-enterprise

I can deploy a **new app** following command from **OpenShift Container Platform Command Line Interface (oc CLI)**

```
//oc new-app --docker-image=<docker-registry-host>:<registry-port>/<image-name:version> --name=customer --insecure-registry=true

$ oc new-app --docker-image=174.24.100.52:8438/spring-customer:v1 --name=customer --insecure-registry=true
```

It is OK, but I want to deploy from OpenShift web console and then go through AddProject>>deploy image section.

[image]

When Firstly I select image name radio button and then typed in the box the following `174.24.100.52:8438/spring-customer:v1`

I have an error like this:

> Internal error occurred: Get https://172.24.100.50:8448/v2/: Tunnel or
>   SSL Forbidden
>
> The image may not exist or it may be in a secure registry. Check that
>   you have entered the image name correctly or create an image pull
>   secret with your image registry credentials and try again.

Comment: It's likely that the web console doesn't have an equivalent to `--insecure-registry=true`, which is why it's failing on the SSL error

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but how can add --insecure-registry=true for web console?

Comment: Are you using minishift?

Comment: No I'm using on the cluster enterprise openshift